# Нужен таймер в python

Tags: python

Делаю в python мини игру нужен ежечасный ящик. Как после функции random запустить таймер на 1 час (в этот час программа должна запрещать открывать ящик, но я мог делать другие функции)

Comment: А зачем таймер? получить текущее системное время и прибавить 1 час

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как отметил в комментарии Clark Devlin, для твоей задачи не обязателен таймер, я предполагаю у тебя есть функция, которая ответственная за открытие инвентаря. Ты можешь просто, в моменте когда тебе нужно начать блокировку установить глобальную переменную с временем окончания её действия. Например так:

```
block_end_timestamp = datetime.now(tz=None).timestamp() + 3600 # + час
```

а при открытии инвентаря добавить проверку на то, что блокировка окончилась:

```
if block_end_timestamp < datetime.now(tz=None).timestamp():
    # Выполняешь открытие инвентаря
```

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помогло

Comment: Сделал всё так пишет “datetime” is not defined

Comment: @Чнрулит `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. Постараюсь впредь тестить перед ответом, а то по памяти не очень получается.

Comment: Это один вариант, еще можно `datetime.now(tz=None) + timedelta(hours=1)`, проверку оставить как было